# Android/Google api : can't get the choosen account

Tags: android, kotlin, google-api, google-fit-api

Im trying to connect to google fit from my android app. but before doing that I need a connected account. 
But even if the user select an account the resultCode==0 and I get developer_error as an error.
Here is my code

**ConnectClass**

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build()
            mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso)
            val intent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent

            (context as MainActivity).startActivityForResult(intent, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST)
```

**MainActivity**

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        val task =
            GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // Sign in succeeded, proceed with account
            val acct = task.result
        }
    }
```